# Spring SEVERE Error : Listener Start?

Tags: java, spring, maven, pom.xml, tomcat6

I get this error, using Apache tomcat 6.0.51. I use spring+ hibernate+ rest.
I can't find reason. What can I do to fix it? 
I try to many way but no solution..

```
 Connected to server
    [2017-04-06 03:05:57,259] Artifact toyotaproject:war exploded: Artifact is being deployed, please wait...
    Nis 06, 2017 3:05:57 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
    SEVERE: Error listenerStart
    Nis 06, 2017 3:05:57 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
    SEVERE: Context [] startup failed due to previous errors
    [2017-04-06 03:05:57,665] Artifact toyotaproject:war exploded: Error during artifact deployment. See server log for details.
    Nis 06, 2017 3:06:07 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
    INFO: Deploying web application directory manager
    F:\apache-tomcat-6.0.51\bin\catalina.bat stop
    Using CATALINA_BASE:   "C:\Users\yusufaslan\.IntelliJIdea2016.3\system\tomcat\Unnamed_toyotaproject_2"
    Using CATALINA_HOME:   "F:\apache-tomcat-6.0.51"
    Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: "F:\apache-tomcat-6.0.51\temp"
    Using JRE_HOME:        "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101"
    Using CLASSPATH:       "F:\apache-tomcat-6.0.51\bin\bootstrap.jar"
    Nis 06, 2017 3:07:13 AM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol pause
    INFO: Pausing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
    Nis 06, 2017 3:07:13 AM org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpAprProtocol pause
    INFO: Pausing Coyote AJP/1.3 on ajp-8009
    Nis 06, 2017 3:07:14 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stop
    INFO: Stopping service Catalina
    Nis 06, 2017 3:07:14 AM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol destroy
    INFO: Stopping Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
    Nis 06, 2017 3:07:14 AM org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpAprProtocol destroy
    INFO: Stopping Coyote AJP/1.3 on ajp-8009
    Disconnected from server
```

this is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>toyotaproject</groupId>
    <artifactId>toyotaproject</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <build>

        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- CXF Dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.18.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.18.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.18.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.18.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
                <!-- Spring Security -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Security -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http-jetty</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-xc</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20090211</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

In server log:

```
Nis 06, 2017 3:05:57 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart SEVERE: Error configuring application listener of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(Webap‌​pClassLoader.java:16‌​98)  
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(Webap‌​pClassLoader.java:15‌​44)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(Stand‌​ardContext.java:4219‌​)'
```

why i get this error ? this is about what ?
I use Intellij Idea and this is....

```
    web.xml <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>src/main/web/applicationContext.xml,src/main/web/Spring-Security.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Spring Security Start -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>
            org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
        </filter-class>
    </filter>
    <!-- Projenin ana url'inden itibaren spring security aktif ediliyor -->
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <!-- Spring Security End -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>



</web-app>
```

this is my applicatiınContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:jaxrs="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd
             http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxrs.xsd">


    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.toyotaproject" />
    <tx:annotation-driven />
    <bean id="dataSource"
          class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/toyotadb" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="12345" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
          class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="SpringJPA_PU"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>
    <bean id='jacksonProvider' class='org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJaxbJsonProvider' />

    <bean id="jpaAdapter"
          class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
        <property name="database" value="MYSQL" />
        <property name="showSql" value="true" />
        <property name="generateDdl" value="true" />
    </bean>
    <jaxrs:server id="restContainer" address="/" >
        <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
            <ref bean="customerWebService"/>
            <ref bean="reservationWebService"/>
            <ref bean="tripWebService"/>
        </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
        <jaxrs:providers>
            <ref bean='jacksonProvider' />
        </jaxrs:providers>
    </jaxrs:server>
</beans>
```

Comment: `Error during artifact deployment. See server log for details.`... so, did you check the server log?

Comment: this is log details .....'Nis 06, 2017 3:05:57 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Error configuring application listener of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:  org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
 at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1698)
 at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1544)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4219)'

Comment: It says: `ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener` -- so, probably some Spring jars are missing in the `war` you are trying to deploy.  You should check if everything is in there.

Comment: which IDE are you using?

Comment: can we have your web.xml? and your servlet config?

Comment: I add web.xml and applicationContext.xml and I use Intellij Idea

Comment: Can you show how you configure your servlet?

Comment: actually my all configure xml file is here,

Comment: what can I add another ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I going to show you what I use to do and it works. let me give you and example.
In place of your applicatiınContext.xml I rather use a springrest-servlet.xml the name is optional but it has to en whit -servlet.xml. then you need to reference this in your web.xml

```
  <servlet> 
        <servlet-name>springrest</servlet-name> 
        <servlet-class> org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet </servlet-class> 
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup> 
    </servlet> 
    <servlet-mapping> 
        <servlet-name>springrest</servlet-name> 
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern> 
    </servlet-mapping>
```

here is my springrest-servlet.xml that is not that much different from your applicatiınContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans    
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd">


    <context:component-scan base-package="com.mycompany.backendhibernatejpa.controller" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven /> 

    <bean id="iAbonneDao" class="com.mycompany.backendhibernatejpa.daoImpl.AbonneDaoImpl"/> 
    <bean id="iAbonneService" class="com.mycompany.backendhibernatejpa.serviceImpl.AbonneServiceImpl"/>

    <!-- couche de persistance JPA -->
    <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
          class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">            
                <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect" />
                <property name="generateDdl" value="true" />
                <property name="showSql" value="true" />
            </bean>
        </property>
        <property name="loadTimeWeaver">
            <bean
                class="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver" />
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">   
        <property name="locations" value="classpath:bd.properties"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- la source de donnéees DBCP -->
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close" >
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${bd.driver}" />
        <property name="url" value="${bd.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${bd.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${bd.password}" />
    </bean>

    <!-- le gestionnaire de transactions -->

    <bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager" />

    <!-- traduction des exceptions -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" />

    <!-- annotations de persistance -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />

    <!--    <bean id="springSecurityFilterChain" class="org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy"/>-->

</beans>
```

Comment: thank you for answer, But ı use Apache cxf here is my cxf, in any case I should add your servlet.xml                                                    'servlet<servlet>
        <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>'